# How to create a panda dataframe from a list

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to visualize the cmb_mpg proportions of the veh_class column from two dataframes.  Im asking for solutions on how to create a new dataframe from the resulting list that I want to plot.

I tried to plot the list, but I get an AttributeError: ’list” object has not attribute ‘plot’

I’d settle for plotting a bar chart of the list if there’s a method.

```
prop = []
vehicle_classes = df_18["veh_class"].unique()

for v_class in vehicle_classes:
    cmb_mpg_08 = df_08[df_08['veh_class'] == v_class]['cmb_mpg'].mean()
    cmb_mpg_18 = df_18[df_18['veh_class'] == v_class]['cmb_mpg'].mean()
    proportion = cmb_mpg_18 / cmb_mpg_08
    prop.append("{}: {}".format(v_class, proportion))

prop
```

This is what the output looks like from the above codeblock.

```
['small SUV: nan',
 'small car: 1.204497798280562',
 'midsize car: 1.290841999329084',
 'large car: 1.2647347740667978',
 'standard SUV: nan',
 'station wagon: 1.2308231787498904',
 'pickup: 1.1420789918199243',
 'special purpose: nan',
 'minivan: 1.088']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
df_18 = pd.DataFrame({'veh_class':['small SUV','small SUV','large car'],
                      'cmb_mpg':[1,2,3]})

df_08 = pd.DataFrame({'veh_class':['small SUV','small SUV',
                                   'large car', 'another car'],
                      'cmb_mpg':[3,4,8,5]})
```

In pandas is the best avoid loops, so use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregate `mean` and for same indices in both output add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html).

```
cmb_mpg_18 = df_18.groupby("veh_class")['cmb_mpg'].mean()
cmb_mpg_08 = df_08.groupby("veh_class")['cmb_mpg'].mean().reindex(cmb_mpg_18.index)

print (cmb_mpg_08)
veh_class
large car    8.0
small SUV    3.5
Name: cmb_mpg, dtype: float64

print (cmb_mpg_18)
veh_class
large car    3.0
small SUV    1.5
Name: cmb_mpg, dtype: float64
```

Then divide by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html), `rename` for another column name and last[`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for column from `index`:

```
proportion = cmb_mpg_18.div(cmb_mpg_08).rename('prop').reset_index()
print (proportion)
   veh_class      prop
0  large car  0.375000
1  small SUV  0.428571
```

Last call [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) for `bar` plot or [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) for line plot:

```
proportion.plot.bar(x='veh_class', y='prop')

proportion.plot(x='veh_class', y='prop')
```

Comment: why do you say it's best to avoid loops in pandas? Your suggestion solved this problem! I didn't even need to call `pd.DataFrame`.  I don't understand why, but `rename` and `reset_index` created the "proportion" as a dataframe.

Comment: It working very well, because it convert series to dataframe. Good luck!